# java generic, wildcard and wildcard subtyping - naturalNumberList.add(new EvenNumber(20)); produces error message

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm currently learning java generic, wildcard and wildcard subtyping. I have come up with the following code. However, when I tried to add an instance of `EvenNumber` to the list using this line of code `naturalNumberList.add(new EvenNumber(20));`, an cryptic error message was shown (see attached picture).

Could someone please kindly explain it to me why `naturalNumberList.add(new EvenNumber(20));` produces an error? Thanks in  advance for any help!

```
public class NaturalNumber {
    private int i;
    public NaturalNumber(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }
}
class EvenNumber extends NaturalNumber {
    public EvenNumber(int i){
        super(i);
    }
}

class PSVM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<EvenNumber> evenNumberList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<? extends NaturalNumber> naturalNumberList = evenNumberList;
        evenNumberList.add(new EvenNumber(100));
        naturalNumberList.add(new EvenNumber(20));//error, for error message, see picture attached below
    }
}
```

Error message:

[image]

Comment: Wildcards aren't needed here. It should only be used in a parameter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves here **completely** different than you think it does.

It effectivally means that *the variable* can hold list instances either `List<NaturalNumber>` or any subclass of it.

Now the compiler can't allow you to add, since it **may** be a list of some other subclass, as `List<OddNumber>`.

---

The real use of wildcards are to add flexibility to method parameters.

```
public void method(List<? extends NaturalNumber> list)
```

You will not be able to add anything to the list, only use its existing elements. To allow to add you'll have to use:

```
public void method(List<? super NaturalNumber> list)
```

Here you won't be able to ensure the types of the elements, so only `Objects` can be taken.

> Remember the rule: PECS. Producer extends, consumer super.

If you want to be able both to take and add, you can't use wildcards.